# Remove text bricks that are defined in an array from input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to edit the value of an input field! To detail i want to delete the text that that is defined an an array from the input:
So if i have for example:

```
<input value="hello what is your">
```

and this array:

```
var arr = ["hello","is"];
```

I want to change the value of the input to:

```
<input value="what your">
```

How should i start? Thanks http://jsfiddle.net/rRXAG/

Comment: _"How should I start?"_ - By giving it a try and coming back when you get stuck on something in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should i start?

1) Iteration - Since you already use jQuery, try with **`$.each`**.
2) **`string.indexOf()`** - returns -1 if it is not present

```
var arr = ["hello","is"];
$.each(arr, function (i, j) {
    var inTxt = $('input').val();
         if (inTxt.indexOf(j) != -1) {
               $('input').val(inTxt.replace(j, ''));
}
});});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rRXAG/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the values are words separated by spaces, you can do this:

1) Store the values into a map

```
var map = {};
for (var i in arr) map[arr[i]] = true;
```

2) Get the value from your input (it's a string) and filter it

```
var inputVal = $('input').first().val();
var newValue = inputVal.split(" ").filter(function(x) { 
  return !map[x]; 
}).join(" ");

// Set new value
$('input').first().val(newValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var val=document.getElementById("yourid").value;
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    val.replace(arr[i],"")
}
document.getElementById("yourid").value=val;
```

Answer (score 1):

This regexp do the job :

```
$('input').first().val().replace(new RegExp(arr.join('|'), 'g'), '');
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rRXAG/2/